# MySQL - Unable to Convert Primary Key to Auto Increment

Tags: mysql, primary-key, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL table where the Primary Key (int) was set by the software to be equal to the Primary Key (auto incremented) of the main table. Because of a change in design I now need the field to auto increment. When I tried to ALTER TABLE it came back with the following:-

```
ERROR 1062: ALTER TABLE causes auto_increment resequencing, resulting in duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `Clinic`.`ClientSupplementary` CHANGE COLUMN `idClientSupplementary` `idClientSupplementary` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.

ERROR 1050: Table 'ClientSupplementary' already exists
```

This has me totally puzzled as '1' is definitely unique as are all the other Primary Key values. Where should I be looking?

Comment: Add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE Clinic.ClientSupplementary;` output in the question.

Comment: You have a row with value `0` or negative. right?

Comment: It seems like you have a duplicate value for `idClientSupplementary`.

Comment: Are there `FOREIGN KEY`s on your ClientSupplementary table? It sure looks like is. Could you also post the complete `ALTER TABLE` statement?

Comment: @ypercube There was a row with a value  of 0 and all other values were NULL. This should not be possible suggesting an obscure coding bug or glitch of some sort.

Comment: No, the value of `0` is messing with the auto_increment. If you can change that value to a positive one and then try again adding the auto_increment property, it will work. I remember having similar trouble. But if you have nulls in the column, you can't make it primary key.

Comment: @ypercube Deleting the meaningless row with a PK of 0 allowed me to set it to AI - problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Your post intrigued me. There is a "workaround" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5402982/470530), but I was curious, so I performed the following tests. You **might** like to try what worked for me below before trying the workaround. If there are `FOREIGN KEY`s, and potential conflicts (duplicates and/or KEY violations), then this won't work. It may be the reason for your error.

I created a table (bill) as follows.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE bill(fred INT, paul VARCHAR(10));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.31 sec)
```

Then inserted some sample values.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO bill VALUES(1, 'adsfd');
    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO bill VALUES(2, 'adsfd');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO bill VALUES(3, 'xxxx');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
```

I then performed a `SHOW CREATE TABLE My_Table\G` (the `\G` gives clear output that can be cut and pasted).

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE bill\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: bill
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `bill` (
  `fred` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `paul` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Just to see the results of my `INSERT`s

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM bill;
+------+-------+
| fred | paul  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | adsfd |
|    2 | adsfd |
|    3 | xxxx  |
+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql>
```

Now, issue your `ALTER TABLE` statement.

`ALTER TABLE bill MODIFY COLUMN fred INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY;`

Recheck the definition of your table.

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE bill\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: bill
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `bill` (
  `fred` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `paul` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fred`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the field `fred` is indeed now a `PRIMARY KEY` and also an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

And to check that it's working.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO bill (paul) VALUES('yyyy');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM bill;
+------+-------+
| fred | paul  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | adsfd |
|    2 | adsfd |
|    3 | xxxx  |
|    4 | yyyy  |
+------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, it's also `AUTO_INCREMENT`ing correctly. I'm not sure why your original statement gave the strange `ALTER TABLE causes auto_increment resequencing` error - maybe a bug of some sort? While performing these tests, I made a number of small errors - MySQL appears to be very fussy about the exact order of steps and the particular syntax of the `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Comment: please see my comment in the question. MySQL is indeed fussy about syntax and often does not give meaningful error messages!  Upvote given.

Comment: @Vérace - Since you started with 1,2,3, we can't tell if the ALTER renumbered them (to 1,2,3) or not.

Comment: I tried -- numbers > 0 are preserved; 0 and NULL are given new (high) numbers -- but high for the moment.  Hence, if 0 turns into 1 and then you try to insert 1, you get dup key.

Comment: Exactly what happened...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no references to `fred` elsewhere, this may be the 'safe' way:

```
ALTER TABLE bill
    DROP COLUMN fred,
    ADD  COLUMN fred INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whist there were a number of useful comments and answers as mentioned in a previous comment of mine the problem was caused a rougue entry which would have corresoned to a PK of zero!. Deleting this solved the problem...

How it got there is the issue...